# Regex to validate password which accept only between fixed length

Tags: java, regex, passwords

I have regex to validate password which accepts password between 10 to 16 only.

However, it returns *true* even if I enter more than 16 characters.

The regex I have is:

```
^(?=.{10,16})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

Comment: Why did you select a solution that [does not work](https://regex101.com/r/sNmqYk/1)?

Comment: @Wiktor I am not getting in which scenario it won't work

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sNmqYk/1. Well, that answer has been changed 3 mins ago, and without anchors, it won't work with `matches()`.

Comment: @Wiktor anyway I am using your regex and its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `(?=.{10,16})` lookahead, you set the minimal length, `10`, the `,16` is not important because you did not add `$` at the end telling to stop matching after 16 chars are matched.

You may either add `$` after `{10,16}`, or remove the lookahead and add `{10,16}` before the final `$`.

I suggest the one that follows the rule: the number of lookaheads must be number of conditions minus 1 (see [rexegg.com for reference](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#password)):

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&+=]).{10,16}$
^^^^                                                ^^^^^^^^
```

[See the **regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/J9qpu3/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[0-9])` - at least one digit
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - at least one lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - at least one uppecase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*[!@#$%^&+=])` - at least one of the special chars defined in the set
- `.{10,16}` - any 10 to 16 chars
- `$` - end of string.

In Java, you do not need the leading `^` and trailing `$` if you use the pattern in the `.matches()` method as it requires a full string match.

Java:

```
if (s.matches("(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&+=]).{10,16}")) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: your explanation is really clear to understand with a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use the regex

```
^[!@#$%^&+=0-9a-zA-Z]{10,16}$
```

see the [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gd5lH4/1).

If you want the password to have atleast 1 of [0-9], [a-z], [A-Z], [!@#$%^&+=] then you can change your regex to

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&+=]).{10,16}$
```

Comment: yes it would, it would match any of the given characters 10 to 16 times

Comment: @Narendra No, this regex does not meet the original requirements. You just need to replace `*$` with `{10,16}$`. And remove `(?=.{10,16})`. Else, add `$` in `(?=.{10,16})` => `(?=.{10,16}$)`

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. Your password would be still valid if you provide any one of the characters that belong to the set, `[!@#$%^&+=0-9a-zA-Z]`. Your expectation is that the password should include at least one `A-Z`, one `a-z`, one `0-9` and a special character the belongs to the set, `[!@#$%^&+=]`.

Comment: @Srichandradeep  and Wiktor let me try what you both suggested.

Comment: @Narendra I posted an answer.

Comment: It wasn't mention in the question if the OP wanted to have atleast one of every mentioned character range, I edited my answer to have that aswell

Comment: @marvel308 It's just intuition. You can simply understand by looking at the RegEx that he had posted.

Comment: Now, you have the same solution as I posted. Why duplicate?

Comment: I just edited the OP's solution to check the number of characters in the end

Comment: @Marvel your modified answer is correct and similar to what Srichandradeep and  Wiktor both suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&+=])(?=.{10,16})
```

The problem with your RegEx is, `.*$`. You are matching a character between 0 and unlimited times. 
Everything looks perfect other than that. I modified the order of Positive lookaheads because the order looks good if you place length restriction at the end.

Comment: [Why is this answer accepted? It does not work at all.](https://regex101.com/r/sNmqYk/1) A `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&+=])(?=.{10,16})$` pattern is yet another example of a regex that never matches any string.

Comment: Sorry. I need to remove `^$` characters. Copy-Paste mistake. BTW, I don't know whether this works perfectly in Java or not. This is based on the scripting language syntax.

Comment: Let me explain: the `^(?=a)$` (and that is basically what your previous regex version reduced to) pattern does not match any string because `(?=a)` gets triggered once at the start of the string (as it is after `^`) and requires an `a` to be the first char in the string. Since `$` requires the end of string right after the start of string, the regex will fail as it won't be able to read the first char in the string.